# Strange error when using "Double.NaN" and "double.MaxValue" in c#

Tags: c#, c#-3.0, crash, double

I have a function in my code like (C#, NET 3.5, Visual Studio 2008):

```
public double function CalculateSomething()
{
   ...
   double a = double.NaN; // Or double.MaxValue, with same behaviour
   ...
}
```

This function is called by the main class, like this:

```
...
double res = o.CalculateSomething();
...
```

Although it looks like incredible (for me, it is) and **ONLY** on certain computers (only in 2 computers from 60) without anything special (WinXP SP3), if I use the "alias" (double.NaN or double.MaxValue) the program is broken without any kind of error screen when the program calls "CalculateSomething", whereas if you assign a particular value, works perfectly.

I mean:

```
public double function CalculateSomething()
{
   ...
   double a = double.NaN; // FAAAAIL!!!!
   double b = -99999; // OK... 
   ...
}
```

Although the change I made, the program can run on all computers, i have curiosity. Does anyone know what may be happening?. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked whether the errors are being supressed?

Comment: Did you test compiled version or rebuilt program on each machine? Probably, the compiler options are different.

Comment: By "broken without any kind of error screen" do you mean that it just exits?

Comment: Yes, none error is suppressed.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen Yes, the program just exit. No "NET. Error" after crash.


@Vissi, it's compiled in one computer only, but... i don't understand this behavior.

Comment: CPU FPU bug? Didn't some early P4 have them?

Comment: Do you have a recursive method or a loop that will only exit if one floating point value is equal to another?

Comment: Double.Nan can cause a FPU exception.  This should not happen in the normal CLR host but it is possible to run unmanaged code that changes the FPU control word and unmasks the exceptions.  This should still give a loud bang, do verify that you don't swallow unhandled exceptions.

Comment: Another option is that these machines have default debugger disabled, so that you don't see the error. Try installing vs on them (or replace the debugger back to drwatson). Hope, it helps.

Comment: Thank you to all... i will study these tips...

Comment: You have the correct .NET runtime installed on all the computers as well? No "We have .NET 4.0 and that should be enough, even though our program is a .NET 2.0/3.5 program"?

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen, all NET runtime installed. The program use NET 3.5, and it was installed on computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the problem:

- I installed NET 4.0, but the program needed NET 3.5. I installed NET 3.5 and it worked.

Really, that rarest thing, i have ever seen.

Thank you all for your responses.