# returning double.NaN doesn't compile

Tags: c#, double, nan, cil

I'm currently working on an old solution developed by somone whom i don't have any contact with.
when i compile it i get the error:
syntax error at token '-' in:     IL_0000:  ldc.r8     -nan(ind)   EntryPoints

And this concern this C# file:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using RGiesecke.DllExport;
using Cola.Keylok;
using System.Windows;

namespace EntryPoints.Utils
{
    internal class UtilsAerotechExports
    {
        [DllExport(CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static ErrorData GetNull(IntPtr handle, TASKID taskid)
        {
            if (!Keylok.IsValid())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("License check error!");
                return new ErrorData() { Code = ErrorCode.ErrorCode_UserDefinedError };
            }
            return Resolver.WrapperAssemblies(Wrappers.Wrapper_Double(DoGetNull))(handle, taskid);
        }

        private static double DoGetNull() => double.NaN;

    }
}
```

The issue seem to originate from the double.NaN but i have no clue what it could exactly be. It looks like the compiler is enable to interprate the NaN.

I tried to use an older version of the Framework (from 4.6 to 3.5 and 4.0) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095116/strange-error-when-using-double-nan-and-double-maxvalue-in-c-sharp)  but the 4.6 is definitly needed. And i honestly don't see why it wouldn't work with the 4.6.

I also tried to remove the System reference and add it back befor restarting VS as administrator.

I tried to replace double.NaN as 0.0/0.0 since this math operation should return a NaN.

It didn't make any diference but i also wrote DoGetNull this way:

```
private static double DoGetNull() 
{
    return double.NaN;
}
```

Comment: Did you try with double.Infinity? Is it possible you made a typo? It is confusing that it claims there is a dash somewhere.

Comment: Appears to be a bug in DLLExport, but according to [this github issue](https://github.com/3F/DllExport/issues/158), *"**NaN** for single and double precision is now processed as `-nan(ind)` instead of `(00 00 C0 FF)` and `(00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 FF)`, respectively. **Temporary solution:** as it was already noticed, please use either our [IL Assembler](https://github.com/3F/coreclr) or custom path to any official version less than 4.8"*

Comment: @RufusL Looks like the bug is actually in `ilasm.exe` which is part of the .NET SDK

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Rufus L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2052655/rufus-l) in the comments:
"Appears to be a bug in DLLExport, but according to this github issue, "NaN for single and double precision is now processed as -nan(ind) instead of (00 00 C0 FF) and (00 00 00 00 00 00 F8 FF), respectively. Temporary solution: as it was already noticed, please use either our IL Assembler or custom path to any official version less than 4.8"

I used the [IL Assembler](https://github.com/3F/coreclr) on the link, restarted Visual Studio and it now compiles properly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).